# Deploy Outlook/Word/Excel Addins with custom internal website

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an outlook addin that I currently deploy by telling the users to browse with windows explorer to a specific file on a share.

I would like to change that such that I would tell the users to browse to a specific internal website using edge/chrome.   Then click on a link to install the addin.

I want to change from file system to browser based so I can deploy it much like any other website we have.    I have add good instructions on the webpage with the link and any number of other advantages.

The file system supports automatic updating as we update the addin and I would want the browser based install to support the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The best what you can do is to publish a manifest URL so users could add it instead if file path on the shared place (of course, if the add-in is not published in the AppStore). You can find all possible ways of deploying Office web add-ins described in the [Deploy and publish Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) article.

Comment: Astaflev, Your guidance is appreciated.  The link you provided is instructive.   It appears the URL method works with Exchange 2013 and 2016.  I think my target will be office365.    I am leaning towards having the system administrator create a share specific for the addin.  I will programmatically control what is on that share.  Do you think MS will continue to support install from share?

Comment: You can post a feature request on Tech Community, they are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .